# Make an absolute reference in a formula to a cell that changes based on the file the macro is applied to

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

For example I have a formula to create a % column and I need the formula to make an absolute reference to the total in a column so that the value in each row is divided by that total. However, there isn't always the same amount of rows in the files the macro is applied to so setting an absolute reference to a specific row and column number provides the wrong value. The code in question that I'm trying to adapt is as follows:

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/R53C2"
```

This code divides the cell to the left of the selection by the absolute reference B53, however sometimes the total for that column is in row 52 or 54 or 55 or some other row so the absolute reference ends up pointing at the wrong cell. I don't know how to word this question in a less confusing manner but essentially I need a formula to make a absolute reference relative to a particular selection that might change from use to use.

[This isn't the whole macro but includes the line in question, I realize there are redundant lines but I want to make the macro work properly before cleaning those up]

```
Sub ExposureColumn()
'
    Range("C6").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "Exposure %"
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/R53C2"
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillUp
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Exposure %"
    Range("C7").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
```

Comment: You can use a variable to build your formula. Ex. if `52`, `53` or `54` are in a variable called `myCol` you can use: `Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/R" & myCol & "C2"`

Comment: If the target is part of a named range or a smart table it might be easier to be more dynamic without a lot of messy looping.  Can you share a screenshot of what you're after perhaps, as well as some code you've tried?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad How do I get the variable to hold the row number I want?

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as an image

Comment: if i understand correctly the total will be in the last row of your %table in col2.  if it is the case you could first find the last occupied row to find the "total" row. Using for instance workskeets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count, 2).end(xlup).row  (replace with appropriate worksheet's name

Comment: @ApisMel the workbooks I apply this macro to are reports downloaded from another program and as a consequence the table isn't formatted as a table in Excel and there is a blank row in between the last table entry and the total row at the bottom.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ablue maybe you could post a snapshot of an example to clarify